# Incremented Select ID Name

Tags: php, html, select

Im trying to loop through some dynamically created select ID's in my php file and I keep running into issues in getting it to work. The error message I keep on receiving is "Notice: Undefined index: selectcell0"

**PHP**

```html
for($i=0; $i<$_SESSION["arr"]; $i++){
 if($_POST['selectcell'.$i]=='Closed')
 {
  echo "Working";
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<td width="10%" align="left" class="no-padding">
  <select id="selectcell<?php echo $i;?>" style="WIDTH: 100px; HEIGHT: 20px" type="text" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <option value="Closed" style="background-color:#66FF66" id="closedcheck">Closed</option>
    <option value="In Progress" style="background-color:#FF0000" id="inprog" selected="selected">In Progress</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

**PHP**

Comment: "Running into issues" what issues are you having?

Comment: I keep on getting this error message: Notice: Undefined index: selectcell0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sean\New\testgen.php on line 15

Comment: Is the SELECT element part of a form and is the form method set to post? You probably only want to run that check if the form has been submitted as well

Comment: Yes to both of them, its part of the form which is set to post @CT14.IT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the name of the select object.

```
<select name="selectcell<?php echo $i;?>">
```

Posting items uses the element name NOT the element ID

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I changed it to use JS getElementById earlier and forgot to change it back lol

Comment: You're welcome, by all means set the ID AND the name, but yeah you need name!